# ReadTheDocs has started insisting on alabaster. I want the default theme back

Tags: themes, read-the-docs

There's lots and lots of advice on how to use a custom theme. I have the opposite problem: Up until recently, all my hosted doc sites used the gorgeous read-the-docs theme *by default* because that's what happens when you do not pick a theme. But for some reason, sophie.... has gotten hung up on the Alabaster theme and I can't figure out how to switch it back.

One vaguely-related question had a suggestion to delete temporary files, but (a) this is quite vague, and (b) I don't think it makes sense now that RTD uses containerized builds. Another suggestion was to make an explicit dependency on the official RTD theme, but for whatever reason that's not plug-and-play on my local machine.

To be clear, a full doc rebuild succeeds without error. It just astonishingly chooses the Sphinx default theme instead of the RTD default theme.

I may once have accidentally had the Alabaster theme set explicitly, but I've commented it out. But then I did that on other documentation projects and they're all on the default theme just fine. As far as I can tell, the configuration is identical in all respects between projects A and B.

[conf.py is here](https://github.com/kjosib/sophie/blob/main/docs/conf.py).

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#sphinx agrees with what you said. I'd file an issue with RTD to correct the docs, because someone else reported the same issue https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/10692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html has the answer. There is no need to futz with project dependencies. Just the `conf.py` edits are sufficient to make this work. Paraphrasing:

```
extensions = [ "sphinx_rtd_theme", ]
html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"
```

You will need to `pip install sphinx_rtd_theme` to build docs locally, but that package is installed by default in the system image that ReadTheDocs now builds with.